# Interaction terms in the curved space Lagrangian

Tags: interactions, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Apologies in advance if this has been posted before, I've browsed through the questions but couldn't find anything similar.

I've been studying some QFT in curved space (mainly using the Birdell & Davies book), and I've noticed that the only fields that are usually discussed in curved space are free fields. This brings me to the following question: if we consider a quantum field in a fixed background (no backreaction), and introduce terms in the Lagrangian corresponding to interactions, does the scattering amplitude $\mathcal{M}_{fi}$ change in any way (at any order)? To keep things relatively simple, let's say we have a minimally coupled scalar field with a $\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4$ interaction. Won't the Green's function depend on the choice of vacuum (because the creation/annihilation operators depend on it), and hence when we go to the interaction picture and do the perturbative expansion in $\lambda$, the scattering amplitude won't be unique? If that is the case, is there some restricted class of metrics when it's possible to define it unambiguously (a timelike Killing field maybe?), and does the amplitude differ from the Minkowski one?

Comment: Interacting field are somewhat treated in Birrell and Davies in the last chapter